# didReceiveRemoteNotification push viewcontroller from tabbarcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have an app that recives push notifications.

In my storyboard I have a tabbarcontroller that has 4 detail views (with a navigation controller embedded).

When I get the push, I am able to set the correct tab bar-controller. But I want to go down the whole line to my detail view.

```
NSString *storyboardId = @"TabFirst";
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
tabBar.selectedIndex = 2;
```

With this I get the correct tabview. But how can I push it to the correct detail view? And I also need to send an object with it (so it can display the correct data).

Thanks.

Comment: I have this code in my app delegate, didReciveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: please explain "go down the whole line to my detail view" ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't yet understood the UINavigationBarController correctly. It's like a stack where you push and pop elements.

Is it ever possible to push 8 th element directly to stack without previous 7 in a stack ??

You need to create instance of the each and every view controller and push it manually via your algorithm.

```
-(void)didReciveRemoteNotification{

    [tabBarController.viewcontroller objectAtIndex:2/*Index of your navigation controller*/];
    // once you get a refrence to you nav you have to push your root view controller and call
    // call messages on each and every view controller which does the transition.
    UITableViewController *tableVC = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tableVC];

    // trigger your events simply with a single message and let every view 
    // controller load it successive viewcontrollers.


    [tableVC didSelectRowAtIndex .. ]; 

}
```

This will also load your data. In short you need trigger chain of events which is followed by your user. But you would be having a data from push notification which will tell you how to load these views. Usually it should not be difficult to trigger this chain of events if you have followed a [chain of responsibility patter](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/objective-c/9781430233305/chapter-17-chain-of-responsibility/what_is_the_chain_of_responsibility_patt) or MVC pattern appropriately. If its difficult for you then there is something wrong with the way you have designed your controllers.

In summary: Load the state of application via a chain of messages depending on the data received from push notification.

Note: Also if you find some other way that might break the invariance of the system